# OneSignal sending notification to all users in segment

Tags: javascript, php, html, onesignal

Overview on what I'm looking to achieve:

A website which users can login (with different permissions defined by a database) and be sent notifications via OneSignal when a status of an order changes.

Currently I have the login system finished and users are placed into the correct segments on OneSignal (e.g. Suppliers). What I'm looking to do is trigger a notification to appear for all 'Suppliers' when an order's status is updated.

Any ideas on how I can go about this? I've looked through all the documentation multiple times so please no comments just saying to do that.

Thanks for any advice.

```
<?php
function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
        "en" => 'Test Message'
    );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "1a95c98a-9349-4876-b9ce-981893b7bf42",
        'included_segments' => array('Suppliers'),
        'data' => array("userType" => "suppliers"),
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage();
$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode( $return);

print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
print($return);
print("\n");
?>
```

Comment: Attempt to solve it, then approach SO with specific issues with what you have attempted. There are likely many solutions to what you want, but no one is going to just write the code for you.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to write the code for me hence the thanks for advice line at the bottom of my question. I was in the process of adding in the code I have tried whilst I saw this comment. I'm really looking for advice from someone who's used OneSignal for web push notifications ideally.

Answer (score 0):

I've used OneSignal for Android.
However, if you are sending notification to a particular segment by making an API call to OneSignal's API end point, then you should try sending a trial notification/test notification with the desired notification data to OneSignal's Server.

After that, construct the same HTTP Request to the API through your code.
For Example, use a RESTful Debugger on Firefox/Chrome and test if you actually are sending the right Request to OneSignal for forwarding your notification.

Also, check on the OneSignal Console if the Segment has been setup correctly.
A correctly setup segment will probably have some tags with corresponding values associated with them, to select the target group of users that receive the notification sent to that segment.

Bottom line, check the whole segmentation setup to be correct by again following all the steps on OneSignal's documentation, if no other solution seems to work.

Hope this helps :)

E.g, use a service like: [Mock Server](http://www.mock-server.com) to mock OneSignal API with desired data.

Comment: I've also used OneSignal for iOS and Android but I'm having no luck with push notifications for the web. It's strange because my Ajax request is returning that it's successful but no having any messages are being sent from OneSignal once this happens. Sending the notification is currently triggered via a button click in the HTML btw. I'm using the example code (with a few small changes) found at: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference (Sent to a specific segment)

Comment: I'm afraid that the only problem I can think of is not setting the tags properly while making the request to the Server. Also a word of advice, all the code that you are using to authenticate your push request to the server should not be on the client side, as it contains server authentication key that OneSignal uses to map a request to a particular OneSignal Project. So try doing it by sending a request to your server with the desired data to be pushed to all users in the segment and further sending the push Request to OneSignal from your App Server.

Comment: Nevertheless, I will still try solving your problem once I get some time and perhaps get back to you with a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will look at moving the code one it's got it all working (didn't want to add another potential reason for it to not work into the mix just yet).